# Execute JavaScript does not execute on Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework

Im trying to get the value of checkbox(true or false). I tried through below build-in key word, but didnt work :

```
Checkbox Should Not Be Selected    //*[text()='Transaction Date']/ancestor::li/descendant::span[text()='disabled']/parent::label/input[@data-id='with.display.ui.panel_disabled.selected']
```

Later I tried 2 other ways: get attaribute & execute Java script, but both didnt work.

1)

```
${temp} =    Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute    //*[text()='Transaction Date']/ancestor::li/descendant::span[text()='required:']/parent::label/input[@data-id='with.display.ui.transactionDate_required.selected']@checked
```

2)

```
${temp} =    Execute Javascript    return     $(window.frames[0].document).find('.open input[data-id="with.display.ui.panel_disabled.selected"]')[0].checked
```

This command works fine on console :

```
$(window.frames[0].document).find('.open input[data-id="with.display.ui.panel_disabled.selected"]')[0].checked
```

Can some one point out what is the issue in my code. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You most probably need to escape the `$` char at the beginning of the Execute Javascript argument; don't have a computer to check the source right now, but robotframework most probably takes it as a variable reference, this changing it.